# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function. SSR with nodejs, react, react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

**Sandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dream-ko68k?file=/server/server.js

**Error**
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4053:17)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
at Object.renderToString (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
at C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server/server.js:16:30
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:323:13)
at C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
at next (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\testingg\server\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)

**Code**
React/index.js
[react/src/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00sFo.png)

**React/App.js**
[react/src/App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGY4r.png)

**Server/index.js** -- node_module to node_modules. but it still doesn't work.
[server/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0lf2.png)

**Server/server.js**
[Server/server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozbQc.png)

**File Structure**
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKsMy.png)

Please help I'm stuck for 2 days now and have no idea on what's wrong. I'm trying to server side render my react application but it doesn't wanna work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck on the same problem, here's what I did.
I pulled `https://github.com/uidotdev/react-router-v5-server-rendering` this repo and wrote my code here.
But I moved to `NextJS` after like 1 or 2 weeks which helped me alot.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

May be unrelated, but I've noticed a `node_module` instead of `node_modules` in server/index.js .

Comment: I changed it to node_modules but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest you make a sandbox with this code, or some other form of copyable text, so more people can have a look.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dream-ko68k?file=/server/server.js